# Аналог Qt Signals & Slots, умеющий посылать сигналы между потоками в чистом C++?

Tags: c++, qt, потоки-данных, многопоточность, boost

Знаю, что есть `boost::signal` но оно вроде так не умеет. Чтобы можно было, скажем, из рабочего потока послать сигнал, и код выполнился в GUI потоке. 
GUI поток - это виндовый Message Loop (скажем `CMessageLoop::Run`), в который мы можем при желании добавить свой коллбэк.
И чтобы это требовало минимум действий от программиста, как в Qt.

Answer (score 1):

Такого механизма не существует. По одной простой причине - в C++ нет единого объекта родителя, как это есть в Qt. Поэтому писать придётся свой механизм, это не так сложно, в целом. Хотя есть вероятность, что в мириадах репозиториев на github подобная библиотека может найтись. Но, повторюсь, её всё равно придется интегрировать в проект, наследую свои объекты(которые хотят получать сигналы) от объектов библиотеки.

Comment: А если поставить вопрос проще, скажем

`runInGuiThread(boost::bind(&MyObject::SomeFunc, a, b))`

?

Comment: Для этого `runInGuiThread` должен иметь доступ к некоторому объекту, вероятнее всего concurrent queue, в который помещается функтор(продукт bind). На стороне GUI потока, эта очередь будет проверятся. Всё это обычный consumer/producer. Это не имеет прямого отношения к сигналам/слотам в Qt

Answer (score 1):

http://sourceforge.net/projects/sobjectizer/
И подобные проекты. Проблема в том, что "просто" здесь не получится, можно скрыть многие детали маршалинга, но синхронизовать "просто" не получится. (Либо код будет трудно сопровождаем и "хрупок", либо состоять из трудноуловимых багов). По этому разрабатываются подобные проекты, требующие некоторой подготовки и дисциплины.

Comment: Да ладно, а как в Qt это работает?

Comment: Внутри одного треда? - так и проблем нет, между разными - мьютексы. dbus/https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B5, между машинами ... tcp/utp & protocols

Comment: Отправка сигналов между объектами, неважно, какому потоку они принадлежат.
Если они находятся в одном потоке - принимающая-функция "слот" вызывается напрямую. Если в разных, то сигнал добавляется в очередь соответствующего потока. 
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#connect

Comment: Это и сказал, мьютексами управляется, очереди потока, все это скрывается под копот, остается внешний пользовательский интерфейс. И не вводите в заблуждение, тем, что неважно кто в каком потоке. Qt используют на платформах, на которых используют неблокирующие структуры, либо мьютексы, первых хороши, если не так много тредов, в случае 1000 и более - быстрее мьютексы, по этому под "капотом" у них это и стоит, сообщения - слишком медленны, но зато можно не переписывать, если менять под кластер (MPI, например).

Answer (score 0):

Действительно, в совсем уж чистом виде такого функционала не достать, но на ум приходит идея взять за основу либо API выбранной ОС, либо 11-й стандарт и писать с использованием condition variables(unix, c++11)/events(WinAPI).
Общая схема следующая: рабочий поток выставляет сигнальную переменную в активное состояние, в это время GUI-поток, находящийся в состоянии ожидания по этой сигнальное переменной, реагирует на событие и вызывает обработчик возникшего события.

---

Ссылки:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/condition_variable/condition_variable/
https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms686915%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Вопрос был в том, как это делать самым простым и удобным в использовании способом. Т.е. чтобы вызывающий код мог ничего не знать ни о каких потоках и  их синхронизации, собственно, как это сделано в Qt. Qt::AutoConnection и в бой.

Comment: Подозреваю, что это тот уровень абстракции, который "из коробки", вряд ли есть в c++. Всё руками.